# rpcgen for Linux

Tags: linux, rpc

We have used rpcgen to create a rpc server on Linux machine (c language).
When there are many calls to our program it still results in a single 
threaded request.
I see that it's common problem from 2004, there is a new rpcgen (or other genarator) that solved this problem?

Thanks,
Kobi

Comment: I believe your question is border-line or perhaps off-topic here, since you don't show any code. You should also edit your question to explain more what is your server doing.

Answer (score 0):

[`rpcgen`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPCGEN) will simply generate the [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) routines. Your server might be coded to have several threads. Learn more about [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).

You probably should not have too many threads (e.g. at most a dozen, not thousands). You could design your program to use some [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern), or simply to have a fixed set of worker threads which are continuously handling RPC requests (with the main thread just in charge of accepting connections, etc).

Read [rpc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rpc.3.html). You might consider not using `svc_run` in your server, but instead doing it your own way with threads. Beware that if you use threads, you'll need to synchronize, perhaps with [mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion).

You could also consider [JSONRPC](http://www.jsonrpc.org/), or perhaps making your C program some specialized HTTP server (e.g. using [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/)) and have your clients do [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) requests (maybe with [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)). See also [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/260611/40065). And you might consider a [message passing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing) architecture, perhaps with [Open-MPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/).

Comment: About the rpcgen: on AIX & Solaris, i managed to create a multithreaded server without any changes of the generated code.

Answer (score 0):

Beware sun version is being abandoned, look for tirpc